# How would you find the probability of the Squared Value of two cards drawn at random

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

**USING COMBINATIONS**
How would the probability of two cards being the square root or square value of eachother. When only two cards are drawn from a deck of 52 without replacement. Ace = 1, Jack 11, Queen 12, King 13.

So the only cards that are able to do this are:
1,1 and 
2,4 and
3,9

Note: **The order of these cards being drawn does not matter nor does their suit**

I simulated this on excel and it occurred around 3-4% of the time but am unsure of how to calculate mathematically.

Comment: No need to simulate.  What is your sample space?

Comment: Just consider all the acceptable outcomes. They are $(1,1), (2,4), (4,2), (3,9)$ and $(9,3)$. Then calculate the probability for each of them. The expression will be the same for each of them, because all the cards are equally likely. You will get something like 
$$ \frac{4}{52} \cdot \frac{3}{51}
$$

Answer (score 1):

pair of aces: $6$ combination

$2,4$ or $3,9$: $16$ combination each

probability is $\frac{6+16+16}{\binom{52}{2}}$ which is about $2.9\%$

Answer (score 0):

For the probability of drawing one 2 and one 4 is $\frac{4*4}{52\choose2}$, same goes for the probability of drawing one 3 and one 9

The probability of drawing two Ace is $\frac{4\choose2}{52\choose2}$

So putting everything together, your total probability is:

$$\frac{4*4}{52\choose2} + \frac{4\choose2}{52\choose2} \approx 2.86576$$